# Without having customerror tag in web.config file ,Customerror mode is set to RemoteOnly as the default value for web api 2 project

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I used the empty template for web api (using VS 2013) for developing services component for our application. I am trying to setup the error details policy for the web api based on the value setup in web.config file using the custom error tag. By default there is no custom error tag present in the web.config file. I used the below mentioned code to set the error details policy in the Register method of WebApiConfig class.

```
var customErrors = 
        (CustomErrorsSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/customErrors");

      if (customErrors != null)
      {
        switch (customErrors.Mode)
        {
          case CustomErrorsMode.RemoteOnly:
          {
            config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.LocalOnly;
            break;
          }
          case CustomErrorsMode.On:
          {
            config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Never;
            break;
          }
          case CustomErrorsMode.Off:
          {
            config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
            break;
          }
          default:
          {
            config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Default;
            break;
          }
        }
```

On debugging the code I noticed that even though there is no customErrors tag under the system.web section in the web.config file ,the variable customErrors is returning a value set up with mode= RemoteOnly

Can anyone help me to know is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
the variable customErrors is returning a value set up with mode= RemoteOnly
```

You're getting this value because this is the default value for custom error element.

```
even though there is no customErrors tag under the system.web section in the web.config file
```

Yes, even though there's not config file in the project but there's always setting specified in Machine.config.

The following default customErrors element is configured in the Machine.config file in the .NET Framework versions 1.0 and 1.1.

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
```

see: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx) article

Comment: Thanks for your answer.The link helped to understand the concept :)